# Discord reaction_add doesn't work in Direct Message channel

Tags: discord, discord.py

I've been troubleshooting this thing for days and this is the last straw.

`Reaction_add` only works if I do `!on_message` in the server 'general' channel, if I directly message the bot, it doesn't do anything. Though, funny thing is, if I message bot directly first and the enter `!on_message` in server general channel, bot reacts in general channel and in direct messages.

After `TimeoutError` I get thumbs down in direct messages.

This is the code, straight from discord.py documentation and I'm using `Bot` as `Client`:

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def on_message(ctx):
    channel = ctx.channel
    await ctx.send('Send me that  reaction, mate')

    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) == ''

    try:
        reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await channel.send('')
    else:
        await channel.send('')
```

It's funny that `wait_for(message, ...)` message works just fine everywhere.

Tried adding this and still no luck.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.dm_reactions = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, description=DESCRIPTION, intents=intents)
```

Comment: What intents have you enabled? Did you enable `intents.dm_reactions`?

Comment: I haven't enabled any. Just started playing with this library. Do I need to declare them globally?

Comment: Nope, the way you did it is fine

Answer (score 1):

It's because `on_message` is a bot event, which means it does not need to be invoked as a command, you can call the command with `()`, but in your case, you are trying to use the command as a event.

This is an event

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = message.channel
    await message.channel.send('Send me that  reaction, mate')

    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == ''

    try:
        reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await message.channel.send('')
    else:
        await message.channel.send('')
```

This is a command, a command needs to be invoked with a function, in this case, it would be your prefix + thumbs `!thumbs` hope both of these help.

```py
@bot.command()
async def thumbs(ctx):
    channel = ctx.channel
    await ctx.send('Send me that  reaction, mate')

    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) == ''

    try:
        reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send('')
    else:
        await ctx.send('')
```

Comment: Nope, same thing happens if I rename the function.

Comment: Aside from the intents issue, @Cohen is correct regarding `@bot.event` vs `@bot.command`. You don't want to decorate `on_message` as a command, since then you won't be able to handle message events.

Answer (score 1):

I added `intents = discord.Intents.all()` and that seems to do the trick, though it's not efficient because I might not need all privileged intents.

Input on issue would be helpful.

Comment: Take a careful look at [this section of the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html). By default, all intents are enabled *except* the privileged intents. The relevant one here is `Intents.members`. This intent is required for a *lot* of member-related functionality to work properly, and is the cause for a lot of confusion and questions as of late.